# In css, when I extend the top margin of my main content, my fixed top nav section margin drops along with the main content

Tags: css, html

I'm designing an extremely simple static blog page with HTML5, SASS & CSS.

Although I've used the 'nav' semantic (for a fixed bar at the top of the page so that it remains no matter how low on the page you scroll) and the 'header' semantic (for more of a title above the articles and below the 'nav') to keep them separate, when I extend 'header' top margin, the 'nav' drops at the same increment. Why? And how to I get the nav to stay put, fixed at the top?

Essentially, my object is to get the 'header' out from under the 'nav', so if there is a better way, I'm all ears.

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
    font-family: helvetica;
} 

nav {
    background: #FFE599;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

nav p {
    margin: 7px auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

header {
    background: #B6D7A8;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 760px;
    margin: 50px 10px 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p>The Lorem Micro Blog</p>
</nav>
<main class="blog-width">
  <aside id="left-side">
    <h2>Check out my vertically centered ad!</h2>
    <img src="href" alt="" />
  </aside>
  <div class="content">
    <header>
      <h1>The Lorem Micro Blog</h1>
      <p>By Foo Bar</p>
    </header>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: There was loads of errors in your HTML with unclosed or not properly closed tags. I fixed those.

Comment: Thank you @connexo . I had trouble posting. I'm learning everything. My code kept being chopped up when I pasted it into the editor with the {} . I have a lot to learn. I had the closed tags beneath my articles which I did not copy in. I see my need to clean up more when asking. Thanks!

Comment: For your question to be of good use to future readers, it is required that you pick the answer which you feel solved your problem best. You do that by clicking the checkmark left of that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html is not correct

if you want to have a nav fixed at the top you need to add `top:0;` and for the header it should be out of the nav tag and you should always add a gap at the top equals to the height of the nav that is fixed at the top and that so you can see the top content

see code below:

```css
body {
      height: 2000px;
      font-family: helvetica;
      padding-top: 30px;
    }
    
    nav {
      background: #FFE599;
      height: 30px;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      top:0;
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }
    
    nav p {
      margin: 7px auto;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
    header {
      background: #B6D7A8;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      height: 50px;
      width: 760px;
      margin: 50px 10px 20px 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
      <p>The Lorem Micro Blog</p>
    </nav>
    <aside id="left-side">
      <h2>Check out my vertically centered ad!</h2>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </aside>
    <div class="content">
      <header>
        <h1>The Lorem Micro Blog</h1>
        <p>By Foo Bar</p>
      </header>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Chiller ! Thanks for the answer. I used it and it worked! So simple. I am brand new so I my vote is not seen but I gave you an up vote. I have only 2 points and could use an up vote if my question has any value. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `top: 0;` for your `nav` element and add some `margin-top` to your `main` element:

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
nav {
  background: #FFE599;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  top: 0;
}
nav p {
  margin: 7px auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
main {
  margin-top: 35px; 
}
header {
  background: #B6D7A8;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 760px;
  margin: 50px 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p>The Lorem Micro Blog</p>
</nav>
<main class="blog-width">
  <aside id="left-side">
    <h2>Check out my vertically centered ad!</h2>
    <img src="href" alt="" />
  </aside>
  <div class="content">
    <header>
      <h1>The Lorem Micro Blog</h1>
      <p>By Foo Bar</p>
    </header>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks @connexo! It worked of course! Much appreciated! I up-voted but it doesn't show because my rep is only two. I could use a vote if the question has value. Thanks!